# Highcharts Image click event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are using Highcharts api in our application.

The below url will give the problem scenario.

http://jsfiddle.net/jnjqt/40/

I need a different click event for each image. But I am getting the same result for each image.
Like if I get alert value of corresponding i for each image, my problem will be solved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't get to jsfiddle from my office.  can you post the highchart code and the clickevent code.

Comment: A common problem with the powerful javascript closures

Answer (score 3):

That’s a more common problem. We use closures in a loop (for or while) and it always keep the last value of the increment.

You just need to return a function when you make the following loop:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
        ......
  }
```

This code should fix your problem:

```
        .on('click', function(i) {
            return function () {
                alert(" image:"+i);  
            }

        }(i))
```

Here the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jnjqt/42/